# 'Copy' variable type from other variable

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, decltype

With the addition of the 'auto'-keyword in c++11, I was wondering if it was possible to 'copy' the type of another variable, or the return type of a function.

For instance, in this code:

```
unsigned short x;
[...] // x is initialized with some value
for(auto i=0;i<x;i++)
{
    [...]
}
```

*i* would be an *int*. Would it be possible to give *i* the same type as *x*, without manually declaring it as *'unsigned short'*?

Basically, what I'm looking for is something like:

```
[...]
for(type(x) i=0;i<x;i++)
[...]
```

Comment: C++11 didn't add the `auto` keyword. It's been there essentially since 1972.

Comment: @KerrekSB false: C++11 introduced the `auto` modifier for local variables, which is mentioned in this question. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: @Croll: That's unrelated. All I said what was that `auto` was already a keyword before C++11.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for [decltype specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype), which is supported from c++11.

> Inspects the declared type of an entity or the type and value category of an expression.

You could use it to declare with the same type of another variable,

```
for(decltype(x) i=0;i<x;i++)
```

or from the return type of a function.

```
unsigned short f();
//...
for(decltype(f()) i=0;i<x;i++)
```

Comment: Oh, I've heared of it before but completely forgot about it and never looked it up. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Can it retrieve the return type from a function as well?

Comment: @Silverlan You mean sth like `decltype(f()) x;`? Yes.